# How to find touch event when finger is swiped over an ImageView

Tags: android

How to find touch event when finger is swiped over an Image.

Relative layout contains multiple image view. they are randomly placed. When I swipe my finger over screen I want to capture image view over which user has crossed his finger.

I am able to capture relative layout touch event Please suggest some way to capture image view 
touched in the swipe action in relative layout.

attached image layout for better understanding.

[image]

CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Rect imageViewArea;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageViewArea = new Rect();
        //imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageViewArea);


        //not working
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //working
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("log", "ACTION_MOVE");

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            //not working 
            if(imageViewArea.contains(x, y)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: please post you code whatever you done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this sample code may help you...

```
    final RelativeLayout layout  =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.detailsView);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Rect imageViewArea = new Rect();
    imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageViewArea);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            if(imageViewArea.contains(x, y)) {
                // swipe is passing over ImageView....
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

```
private ImageView imageView;
private Rect imageRect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (imageRect == null) {
        imageRect = new Rect();
        imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageRect);
    }
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (imageRect.contains(x, y)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "touch passing over imageView");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The method contains(int, int) is undefined for the type ImageView

Comment: not working 
if(imageViewArea.contains(x, y)) {
                // swipe is passing over ImageView....
            }

Comment: @Kanaiya see my edited code... return **true** in OnTouchEvent

Comment: @Kanaiya remove OnTouchListener for ImageView. if still problem exists, let me know...

Comment: yes its working can you tell me what is wrong in my code and what is right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44227/discussion-between-kanaiya-and-gopal-rao)

Comment: I think, when you call getGloabalVisibleRect() on any View in onCreate(), it returns null or empty Rect as still drawing is not performed... so you should get Rect in OnTouchListener...

Answer (score 0):

Set [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to image or create own ImageView clas with overriden onTouch method

Comment: Maybe create transparent overlay over relativeLayout with images that catches all touch events and than check action if swipe is over imageView or not

Comment: I think your layout should look like this:
relativeLayout
imageViews(multiple)
TransparentView

TransparentView catches all touch events and give it to relative layout. Than RelativeLayout checks if (child) ImageView was is touched and than sends touch to imageView