# How to create a pattern Lock app

Tags: android, locking

I am new to android, In my app I just need to add a screen like pattern lock, what exactly I want to do is, no need to create/ set a pattern.Just design a screen with 9 dots, and when user draw some pattern and I need to get those pattern value.For design I used PatternView but how can I get the user drawer pattern? I already google on this, but I found there they setting the pattern lock, I don't want that.I just want is when I draw something on PatternView it just return the value like,suppose like if I draw a pattern like 2365 dots it will return an integer value like 2365.

I already tried [haibison.github.io/android-lockpattern](http://haibison.github.io/android-lockpattern/) but my app is different than this.I just want to draw a pattern and get result, no need to create and confirm screens. No need to save the result in shared preferences. I just want compare the drawn pattern value with my predefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Following is idea on how to go for this:

1. Start with a table view for your layout and create a 3 x 3 grid of image views (dots).
2. override onTouchListener on your activity to detect touches on images. refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856678/1529129) for details.

> ```
> private ImageView imageView;
> private Rect imageRect;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>     super.onTouchEvent(event);
>     if (imageRect == null) {
>         imageRect = new Rect();
>         imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageRect);
>     }
>     int x = (int) event.getX();
>     int y = (int) event.getY();
>     if (imageRect.contains(x, y)) {
>         Log.i(TAG, "touch passing over imageView");
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```

example is for 1 image view you have to build it for 9.

3. as and when touch is detected append the index of imageview to a string.
4. once an image is touched stop detecting touches on it.
5. perform desired operation when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is detected

Comment: this is not how it works :). try these steps and come back if you face any issue.

Comment: Can anybody help on this? I am totally new to this,I can't understand what to do?